# Acerca de la negación de un enunciado

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, modismos, adverbios, negación

Hace unos días, me surgió una duda acerca del uso de la palabra **tampoco** mientras mantenía una conversación. Más precisamente:

> A: Aún no tengo profesor de ecuaciones diferenciales.
>
> B: Yo también no tengo profesor de ecuaciones diferenciales.

La duda surgió de la corrección que me hizo el interlocutor, pues mencionó que debí haber dicho "Yo **tampoco** tengo profesor de ecuaciones" en lugar de "Yo **también no tengo** profesor de ecuaciones"

¿Ambas formas son correctas o la que usé es errónea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yo creo que se usa `también` para expresar semejanza o igualdad con una sentencia **positiva**. Se usa `tampoco` para expresar semejanza o igualdad con una sentencia **negativa**.

La [RAE explica](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=upRhBVh14D6CPrVZhk) que `tampoco` es un adverbio que se usa "para negar algo después de haberse negado otra cosa"

La forma correcta es por tanto "yo **tampoco** tengo", ya que primero niega alguien tener profesor de ecuaciones y después negamos nosotros.

Para usar "también" en  la segunda frase tendríamos que deshacernos de esa "negación después de una negación".

> A: No tengo profesor de ecuaciones diferenciales.
>
> B: Yo también estoy sin uno./ Yo también estoy en esa situación.

En ese caso B no está usando una negación o sentencia negativa, y se usaría `también`.

Comment: Curiosamente, la locución *também não* («también no») es mucho más usado en el português que *tão-pouco* («tampoco»).  Quizás cerca de alguna frontera con Brasil o Portugal podría surgir *también no* (o por lo menos, la duda de si existe) por influencia lusófona.

Comment: Que yo sepa "también no", a parte de correcto o incorrecto, no se usa en ningún país de lengua hispana. Sinceramente, suena **extremadamente** raro, es una de estas expresiones que "duelen" cuando la escuchas o la lees; no pasa desapercibida.